# I am getting this error: MermaidExtension.extendMarkdown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'md_globals'

Tags: python-3.x, markdown, mermaid

This was working not too long ago (probably inadvertently upgraded a library somewhere.)  All of my libraries are up to date.
Here is the stack trace:

```
 File "C:\Users\jorda\Documents\projects\python\poolBoy\flaskApp.py", line 422, in about
    html += markdown.markdown(text, extensions=['md_mermaid', 'fenced_code', 'tables'])
  File "C:\Users\jorda\Documents\projects\python\poolBoy\venv\lib\site-packages\markdown\core.py", line 386, in markdown
    md = Markdown(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jorda\Documents\projects\python\poolBoy\venv\lib\site-packages\markdown\core.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.registerExtensions(extensions=kwargs.get('extensions', []),
  File "C:\Users\jorda\Documents\projects\python\poolBoy\venv\lib\site-packages\markdown\core.py", line 125, in registerExtensions
    ext.extendMarkdown(self)
TypeError: MermaidExtension.extendMarkdown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'md_globals'
```

Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Must have upgraded Markdown inadvertently.  I added the following to my requirements and it is working fine now:

```
Markdown<3.2
```